# Global exception handler bypassed in C# async block

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2012, async-await, windows-phone-8

What could possibly be wrong with the following block in WP8 SDK? It causes an unhandled exception to be thrown, crashing my debugging session in VS 2012:

```
try
        {
            List<StorageFile> files = new List<StorageFile>();
            foreach (StorageFile file in (await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFilesAsync()))
                if (Path.GetExtension(file.Name).ToLower() == ".item") files.Add(file);
            return files;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var x = e.Message;
            return new List<StorageFile>();
        }
```

When I step through, the offending statement is GetFilesAsync(), but I believe at the time I call it, there is no reason why it should fail. In any case, shouldn't my exception handler be called when something goes wrong?

Comment: Is there app unhandled exception handler firing? If so, what's the EventArgs?

Comment: The Windows Phone SDK isn't fantastic at handling exceptions in async calls. But the RTM version of the SDK made it a lot better. Can you clarify a bit on what's actually happening?